# Formatting HTML with jQuery inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update numbers on a page based on button pushing by a user. I have it working, but when the number updates, the text is no longer formatted like it came in a <code></code> block. Here's the code I'm using minus any effort to control the format:

```
<script>
    var countUp = function() {
        $("#num").html(parseInt($("#num").html()) + 1);
        $("#textWithNumInIt").html("The number is now"+$("#num").html() );
    }
</script>

<p id="textWithNumInIt"><code>The number is 0</code></p>
```

I've tried putting <code></code> tags inside the jQuery, with and without escape characters. I've tried using .val() and .text() to set the text in an effort to leave the formatting alone. I've tried using a span around the number itself, but then the value doesn't even update.

This is the first time I have changed HTML using jQuery inside a javascript function, so the trouble might have something to do with that. Any help would be awesome, and if you have advice on a totally different way to do this, please share.

Comment: Incidentally, [you should always use `parseInt` with a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Wrapping in `<code></code>` seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PPeFS/

Answer (score 2):

When you edit the contents of the `textWithNumInIt` paragraph, the `<code>` tags inside that paragraph are naturally replaced as well. This should work:

```
$("#textWithNumInIt").html("<code>The number is now "+$("#num").text()+"</code>" );
```

Comment: I had already tried that, and it didn't work. I just tried wrapping <b></b> tags around it instead, and the bold showed up. It is possible that the framework I'm working in prevents certain tags from being used inside the javascript?

Comment: No idea. [As EP pointed out, a self-contained example works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/PPeFS/), so you need to provide us with an example where it doesn't work before we can try to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this -

```
$('#textWithNumInIt code').html("The number is now "+$("#num").text() )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you parseInt it, it gets converted into plain text and the `<code>` wrapper is gone. Use this and you will be on your path.

```
var countUp = function() {
    var t = parseInt($("#num").text()) + 1);//using text() to avoid any unintentional html tag issues
    $("#num").html(t);
    $("#textWithNumInIt").html("<code>The number is now "+t+"</code>" );
}
```

or otherwise you can continue with your code by making a simple edit.

```
var countUp = function() {
    $("#num").html(parseInt($("#num").html()) + 1);
    $("#textWithNumInIt code").html("The number is now"+$("#num").html() );
}
```